# Access Iphone Pim Data via web app

Tags: iphone

i think i know the answer to this question, but just want to make sure before i dismiss the possibility.

is it possible with user permission for my web app to access pim data like the address book on a iphone, similar to how a web app can access the location service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save you time, no this is not possible, at least not at this time.
(as an iPhone user...I hope it stays this way :)

Comment: yeah i would imagine that it would could be pretty prone to abuse.